# References for Tibetan?

Tags: tibetan

What good digital references exist for Tibetan?

There's a list here on [lexilogos](https://www.lexilogos.com/english/tibetan_dictionary.htm), but some of the links are dead and the rest are archive.org pages with pdfs.

---

For instance:

I have this proverb in《中国谚语集成 四川卷》on p. 88:

[image: aba]

> 公鸡不叫天也明，
>   依查拉不叫天也黑｡<sup>②</sup>

where the footnote says:

[image]

> ②依查拉：藏语，猫头鹰。

The [Tibetan & Himalayan Library](http://www.thlib.org/reference/dictionaries/tibetan-dictionary/translate.php) doesn't support Chinese and doesn't return anything for an English word search for `owl`.

(འུག་པ། doesn't seem to fit either).

What choices do I have to look up: 依查拉, owl, 猫头鹰?

Comment: Tibetan ain't Chinese, is it?

Comment: @busukxuan you're correct. But linguistically they are thought to be of the same language family though.

Comment: @Vim yeah Sino-Tibetan, but doesn't this make it kinda off-topic here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Chinese

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PanLex (translate.panlex.org) for languages with little to no resources otherwise widely available.

The standard Tibetan word for *owl* is **འུག་པ** (*'ug pa*)

If we try translating from "鷹", we get closer matches like

- ཁྲ་གླག (*khra glag*)
- གླག (*glag*)

How about eagle?

- བྱ་གླག (*bya glag*)

I think *khra glag* might be a close match for 查拉, but I don't know anything about Tibetan.

---

PanLex works through association though, so if a lexical collection doesn't contain a direct translation it will try to match from different languages with a translation available. You will very likely end up getting incorrect translations if the number of node points in series is too high (parallel node points in contrast increase the confidence in a given translation).